# Postgresql - retrieve rows within criteria within 30 day span

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables

```
AdmittedPatients(pid, workerid, admitted, discharged)
Patients(pid, firstname, lastname, admitted, discharged)
DiagnosticHistory(diagnosisID, workerid, pid, timeofdiagnosis)
Diagnosis(diagnosisID, description)
```

Here is an SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e7403

Things to note:

- AdmittedPatients is a history of all admissions/discharges of patients at the hospital.
- Patients contain all patients who have records at the hospital. Patients also lists who are currently staying at the hospital (i.e. discharged is NULL).
- DiagnosticHistory contains all diagnosis made.
- Diagnosis has the description of the diagnosis made

Here is my task: list patients who were admitted to the hospital within 30 days of their last discharge date. For each patient list their patient identification number, name, diagnosis, and admitting doctor.

This is what I've cooked up so far:

```
select pid, firstname, lastname, admittedpatients.workerid, patients.admitted, admittedpatients.discharged
from patients 
join admittedpatients using (pid)
group by pid, firstname, lastname, patients.admitted, admittedpatients.workerid, admittedpatients.discharged
having patients.admitted <= admittedpatients.discharged;
```

This returns pid's from 0, 1, and 4 when it should 0, 1, 2, and 4.

Comment: since admitted date is on the patient record, all we'll be able to do is look at the most recent admittance is that enough?

Comment: It's returning data for me not that you've edited the last line out.

Comment: @xQbert - Yes. I should mention this is the first database I have written. Obviously, the design isn't elegant.

Comment: @Scott - Edited again.

Comment: @piofusco  just a word of warning..  Anytime you encounter structure problems with a database really give it some thought.  Any development which uses that structure will have to change if it's not scaleable now.  This could cause significant re-work later.  Getting the design right and scalable is very important, or you will have to continue to rework alienating developers and customers.

Comment: @xQbert - Thanks for the warning. I am not ignorant to any of the ideas you mentioned. Obviously, I have a long way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why out need group by or having here... no aggregate...

```
SELECT A.pid, firstname, lastname, A.workerid, P.admitted, A.discharged
FROM  patients P
INNER JOIN  admittedpatients A 
  on P.pID = A.pID
WHERE date_add(a.discharged, interval 30 day)>=p.admitted
and p.admitted >=a.discharged
```

updated fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc33c/30/0

Didn't get into returning all your needed fields but as this gets the desired result set I imagine it's just a series of joins from here...

Updated to postgresql:

```
SELECT A.pid, firstname, lastname, A.workerid, P.admitted, A.discharged
FROM  patients P
INNER JOIN  admittedpatients A 
  on P.pID = A.pID
WHERE a.discharged+ interval '30 day' >=p.admitted
and p.admitted >=a.discharged
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e7403/1/0

Comment: I have updated the fiddle to Postgres 9.3.1. A quick google search leads me to believe that date_add() in MySQL differs from PostgreSQL. Suggestions on how to get this to work in PostgreSQL?

Comment: @Piofusco Added response to PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see any diagnostic info in the fiddle, so I didn't return any.

```
select pid
,p.lastname,p.firstname 
,ad.lastname,ad.firstname 
from AdmittedPatients as a
join AdmittedPatients as d using (pid)
join Patients as p using (pid)
join AdminDoctors as ad on ad.workerid=a.workerid
where d.discharged between a.admitted-30 and a.admitted
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a rather basic WHERE clause error here:

Admitted cannot be *both* before discharged AND after discharged+30

Also you have an extra semicolon before your whole query is ended, probably throwing out the last line altogether.

I think you're looking for admitted=discharged

Comment: I read the whole question.  I have a problem with the DB design how admission date is in the Patient table when it exists in the AdmittedPatients table.  It's certainly not how I'd write the query.  But the where clause error will always result in 0 results if the 2 criteria are contradictory

Comment: Edited query - didn't mean for that last line.